# Free real-time source for satellite image

Tags: uses-of-open-data, geospatial, environment, real-time

I am interested to apply image processing for analyzing image map. However, I require a real-time source to follow any change during a given time period. Can anyone introduce any online and free real-time source to work with?

I need these image to detect the source of the dust.

Answer (score 1):

After looking through a few NASA repositories, I stumbled upon the [EUMETSAT Website](http://oiswww.eumetsat.org/).

This site is a source for near-real-time climate and environmental images from orbit. They offer a WMS service as well as host images of different variables, including [dust](http://oiswww.eumetsat.org/IPPS/html/MSG/RGB/DUST/FULLDISC/). Due to the nature of satellite images, having a true real-time source is not very reliable as remote sensing adjustments and calculations need to be performed after collection.